# NSMutableArray storing int without duplicates

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, arc4random

I'm trying to create a NSMutableArray in Xcode 5 where I randomly generate a number between 1 and 12 and store them as integers. The problem is sometimes it will generate the same number twice, which is not desirable.

```
//Load array
NSMutableArray *theSequence = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Generate the Sequence
for (NSInteger i=0; i < difficultyLevel; i++) {
    int r = arc4random()%12 + 1;

    //Check here if duplicate exists
    [theSequence addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:r]];
}
```

Where difficultyLevel is currently 4, as there should be 4 integers stored.

I've tried other answers on Stack Overflow with no success, would anyone be able to tailor some sort of loop before [theSequence addObject:..] so that when I show the numbers in a label they are unique? Thank you in advance!

Harry

Comment: Just FYI, you're introducing [modulo bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modulo_bias) with `arc4random()%12`. `arc4random_uniform(12)` is a better alternative. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the order of the `int`s does not matter (they are random, anyway) replacing `NSMutableArray` container with [`NSMutableSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html) will let you avoid duplicates. All you need to do now is check the size of the container, and stop when you reach the desired size of four:

```
NSMutableSet *theSequence = [NSMutableSet set];

do {
    int r = arc4random()%12 + 1;
    [theSequence addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:r]];
} while (theSequence.count != difficultyLevel);
```

Note: If for some reason the insertion order is important, you can use `NSMutableOrderedSet`.

Comment: If the order does matter, the OP could simply use `NSMutableOrderedSet` btw.

Comment: @David Thanks, David! That's a very nice comment.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Works like a charm, you absolute star! :)